# IXMLHTTPRequestPtr send hangs

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Here is code nip to reproduce the problem. It hangs when i make the send request as shown below in the code

the platform is windows 7

and i am using

visual studio community edition for this.

Please let me know what is wrong here.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

    #import "msxml6.dll"
    using namespace MSXML2;



    void XMLHttpRequestSample()
    {
    IXMLHTTPRequestPtr pIXMLHTTPRequest = NULL;
    BSTR bstrString = NULL;
    HRESULT hr;

    CoInitialize(NULL);

    try {
    hr = pIXMLHTTPRequest.CreateInstance("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
    SUCCEEDED(hr) ? 0 : throw hr;

    hr = pIXMLHTTPRequest->open("GET", "http://www.google.com", false);
    SUCCEEDED(hr) ? 0 : throw hr;

    hr = pIXMLHTTPRequest->send();
    SUCCEEDED(hr) ? 0 : throw hr;

    bstrString = pIXMLHTTPRequest->responseText;

    MessageBox(NULL, _bstr_t(bstrString), _T("Results"), MB_OK);

    if (bstrString)
    {
    ::SysFreeString(bstrString);
    bstrString = NULL;
    }

    }
    catch (...) {
    MessageBox(NULL, _T("Exception occurred"), _T("Error"), MB_OK);
    if (bstrString)
    ::SysFreeString(bstrString);
    }

    }
    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
    return XMLHttpRequestSample();
    }
```

Comment: I am able to solve the problem. The visual studio was hanging while it is trying to load symbol for the library rasapi32.dll windows on windows 7. I did the following to fix this.

Comment: DEBUG->OPTIONS & SETTING in visual studio.

Comment: Cleaned the symbol cache. Then it worked fine for me.